# What's difference between "car wheels" and "wheels of car"

Tags: grammar, differences

What is differences between these two phrases:

> 1. Car wheels
> 2. Wheels of car

Comment: One is two words, the other is three.  (And, of course, an article or two would generally be present with both, but exactly how/where is context-dependent.)

Comment: When I read *wheels of car* I think of wheels that are made out of a car. Like *blocks of cheese* or *stacks of books*. However, I can't express this as a "rule": while I think of *car wheels* as wheels that belong to a car, *tin can* does not mean a can that belongs to tin but a can that is made out of tin. So, there is some inconsistency.

Comment: @JasonBassford - In most contexts "wheels of car" is bad grammar (unless the wheels are indeed somehow made of "car").  As I said in my earlier comment, an article or two is needed, probably in both cases.

Comment: @HotLicks: Is it related to specific grammar?

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, **car wheels** refer to wheels on their own:

> I'm selling this set of four *car wheels* from a [make] [model]. They also fit [model2]...

On the other hand, **wheels of a car** or **wheels of the car** refer to the wheels as mounted on a car, as appendages of that car (even when they are temporarily removed). Due to the construction with the preposition *of*, they put some emphasis on the concrete car that the wheels belong to.

However, I can imagine a context in which you are describing a car and when you reach the wheels, you can call them *the wheels*, when the modifier (the car) is clear implicitly, or *the wheels of the car*, or *the car wheels* with basically no difference in meaning.

Comment: Is there any grammar that refers to this question? Especially phrase no.1

Comment: I would say that **car wheels** is equivalent to **wheels for a car**. And **[the] car's wheels** is equivalent to **wheels of [the] car**.